# Autohotkey not always sending keys? (Whats going on here)

Tags: autohotkey, obs

**Basically I don't understand what's going on, any clarification would help**

I am trying to set the hotkey "**_**" and "alt **_**" in my program. So I made an autohotkey script to replace "/" with "_" and ever other press with "alt _" but it doesn't appear to always work in my program? (unless i spam the command)

My script:

```
/::
Send _ ;if I keep clicking "/" I always get the desired effect
return
```

But when I open up my program and press "/" its not launching the specified scene unless I do something like this (however its always replacing "/" with _ in text.

```
/::
Send_ ; This code works fine, I don't need to keep clicking "/" it works the first time but the codes awful
Send_
Send_
Send_
Send_
return
```

When I use the above code the streamlabs OBS program picks it up every single time and swaps to the appropriate scene. But when I just use one `Send _` it sometimes works right away and sometimes I need to press it multiple times.

My full code (which is seemingly working fine) is as follows:

```
+/:: ; This is the hotkey I press "Shift /" to start the script
toggler := !toggler ; this changes a boolean every time the script is run
if (toggler) { ; Every odd run this happens (hides scene)
    Send +-
    Send +-
    Send +-
    Send +- ;; I feel like all these lines are redundant
    Send +-
    Send +-
    Send +-
    Send +-
    Send +-
    Send +-         
} else { ; every even run this happens (shows scene)
    Send !+-
    Send !+-
    Send !+-
    Send !+- ;; again idk why I need all these lines instead of just 1
    Send !+-
    Send !+-
    Send !+-
    Send !+-
    Send !+-
    Send !+-
}
return
```

Basically streamlab obs doesnt let you toggle scenes on/off with the same hotkey so thats what I did but i cant stand my solution :(

Comment: Can you try your script on something like notepad to see if it's sending the commands you want? I tested your script and for it to work I have to let go of the shift key every time. Otherwise the hotkey only works the first time. Also you could try using `SendInput` instead of `Send` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: See what happens if you [ControlSend](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) the inputs to OBS

Comment: If the program is running with admin privileges, then AHK won't intercept the key presses properly.